# Using memcache with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, memcached

I have server on Node js.
When I receive POST request, i parse the body of POST request and write the results to memcache.

For some time everything works perfect. But after some time I get these errors.

```
{ Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:804:14) code:     'EPIPE', errno: 'EPIPE', syscall: 'write' }

Unhandled rejection Error: Memcache connection lost
    at /src/Node/node_modules/memcache-plus/lib/connection.js:158:25
    at List.__iterate (/src/Node/node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js:2208:13)
    at List.forEach (/src/Node/node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js:4383:19)
    at Connection.destroy (/src/Node/node_modules/memcache-plus/lib/connection.js:157:24)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/src/Node/node_modules/memcache-plus/lib/connection.js:206:30)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
```

As the result Node server is still running, but I can no longer write to memcache as the connection is lost.

Why is the connection to memcache lost?
Can i fix this or should i just handle that rejection exception?

Comment: We obviously have no idea why the connection to memcached gets lost. Start by looking in logfiles, or running memcached with extra debugging (if possible), to see if that provides any clues. Also, check out the [`onNetError`](http://memcache-plus.com/initialization.html#options) option. And lastly: are you sure that it _actually_ works? The module you're using buffers up to 1000 memcache operations by default before starting to throw connection errors.

Comment: it seems to work fine, as i can get data FROM memcache after I parse and store it. After this error I can still get data from memcahe using php, but no longer able to write or update anything using node.